# Does bounded expectation imply almost sure boundedness for the sample mean?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d random variables from a probability distribution. Further there is a positive constant M such that $|E[X]|<M.$ My question is does the strong law imply that the sample mean $\bar{X_n}$ is almost surely bounded (i.e $P(|\bar{X_n}|>C)=0$,$\forall n\geq n_0$ and some constant $C>0.$) for very large n?

Answer (score 1):

No.

For instance let the $X_i$ have standard normal distribution.

Then also $\bar{X}_n$ has normal distribution hence $P(\bar{X}_n>C)>0$ for every $n$ and every $C>0$.

Comment: Do you know of  conditions under which the claim is true?

Comment: If $P(X_1>C)>0$ then also $P(\bar{X}_n>C)>0$ so what you need is that also $X_1$ is a.s. bounded.